# click in table link displays next div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with multiple (could be 100) rows that need to display a div within the table on click. The div is generated and immediately follow the row.I've been trying the next commend and can get it work but it shows all the divs, not just the one following immediately after.

Here's my script with jquery loaded prior:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("div.pop_up").css({'display':'none','opacity':'0'})
    $("div.trans").css({'display':'none'})

//this is the code in question
    $("a.trigger").click(   
    function () {
        $(this).parent().next('.pop_up').css({'display':'block'});
        $(this).parent().next('.pop_up').animate({
          opacity: 1
        }, 500);

        $("div.trans").css({'display':'block'});
      }
    )


    $("div.close").click(

      function () {
        $("div.pop_up").css({'display':'block','opacity':'0'});
         $("div.trans").css({'display':'none'});
      }
    )
  });
</script>
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<table width="300px" border="0">
    <tr>
       <td><a href="#" class="trigger">View Answers</a></td>
        <td>Exclusive</td> 
       <td>Johnny</td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><div class="pop_up" style="background-color:#ccc">
            <div class="close"></div> 

            <p><strong>View Answers: Johnny</strong></p>

            </div></td>
   </tr>

    <tr>
       <td><a href="#" class="trigger">View Answers</a></td>
        <td>Exclusive</td> 
       <td>Bobby</td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><div class="pop_up" style="background-color:#ccc">
            <div class="close"></div> 

            <p><strong>View Answers: Bobby</strong></p>

            </div></td>
   </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: It's invalid to have a `<div>` as a child of a `<table>`. It must be in a `td` or a `th`.

Comment: @cookiemonster - [Technically](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1) it should be `thead, tbody, tfoot, caption, colgroup, caption` or an (implicit `tbody`) `tr` (or `td` and `th` if it's really dirty).

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I'm not sure what you're getting at. A `div` wouldn't be a valid child of any of those elements, except for the `td` and `th`. Or am I misunderstanding your point?

Comment: @cookiemonster - You said a `td` or `th` would be valid in a `table` tag. Technically, that is incorrect.

Comment: OK, so I've enclosed the div... any other ideas?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I said that the `div` must be in a `td` or a `th`. Given the rest of the HTML, I guess I assumed that he would know that a `td` belongs in a `tr`, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (Haven't tested thoroughly though):

```
 $("a.trigger").click(

 function () {
     $(this).parent().parent().next().find('.pop_up').show();
 });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Frikkievb! This seams to be working. I'll try it in the actual file but so far so good in the test page. I did change it to:     `$(this).parent().parent().next().find('.pop_up').stop().css({'display':'block'});`

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting the parent of anchor, that is n TD, and there is not and next element with .pop_up class.

try this:

```
$(this).parents('tr').next().children('.pop_up')
```